# Android get all files from folder in sdcard

Tags: android

I am try to get all files from download folder with this code
The code give me mistake!
What is the problem with this code?
Is there any way to get the files?
[image: this the mistakes image]

This is my code

```
ArrayList<File> mFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
File mDirectory;
String folderPath = "/mnt/sdcard/download";
mDirectory = new File(folderPath);
ExtensionFilenameFilter filter = new ExtensionFilenameFilter();

// Get the files in the directory
File[] files = mDirectory.listFiles(filter);
if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
    for (File f : files) {

        mFiles.add(f);
    }

    Collections.sort(mFiles, new FileComparator());
}
```

Is this need support libs?

Comment: Import classes `ExtensionFilenameFilter` and `FileComparator`.

Comment: I am new at android. How to import this classes? Please help me... What i must to do?

Comment: i think you need to read some basic tutorials about Java in general, you are missing the very basics

Comment: are u mean import ExtensionFilenameFilter;  ??

Comment: Yazan?? Just give a tutorial link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After declaring package of class, import classes `ExtensionFilenameFilter` and `FileComparator`.

Considering class `ExtensionFilenameFilter` is present in package `a`

and `FileComparator` in `b.c`, write:

```
package your_package_name;

import a.ExtensionFilenameFilter;
import b.c.FileComparator;

... //Rest of code.
```

Read official Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: Can u see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977223/android-file-filter